# Save variable in swift even when app is turned off

Tags: ios, swift, session

Do you guys know how to save a var in swift, even when the app is closed.

When someone opens the app on his phone for the first time he can choose a name, what I want is, if he selected a name at the first time. He don't need to choose anymore and the name is saved even when the app is closed and turned on again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).
With the `NSUserDefaults` class, you can save settings and properties related to application or user data.

ex:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Foo", forKey: "name")
```

and then to read

```
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("name")
{
    println(name)
}
```